# MPI own code to find the minimum value in a vector

Tags: mpi, broadcast, min, reduce

I am trying to write my own MPI function that would compute the smallest number in a vector and broadcast that to all processes. I treat the processes as a binary tree, and find the minimum as I move from leaves to the root. Then I send message from the root to the leaves through its children. But I get a segmentation fault when I trying to receive the minimum value from the left child (process rank 3) of process rank 1 in an execution with just 4 processes ranked from 0 to 3.

```cpp
void Communication::ReduceMin(double &partialMin, double &totalMin)
{
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double *leftChild, *rightChild;
    leftChild = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    rightChild = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
    leftChild[0]=rightChild[0]=1e10;
    cout<<"COMM REDMIN: "<<myRank<<" "<<partialMin<<" "<<nProcs<<endl;
    MPI_Status *status;
    //MPI_Recv from 2*i+1 amd 2*i+2
    if(nProcs > 2*myRank+1)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" waiting from "<<2*myRank+1<<" for "<<leftChild[0]<<endl;
        MPI_Recv((void *)&leftChild[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+1, 2*myRank+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status);             //SEG FAULT HERE
        cout<<myRank<<" got from "<<2*myRank+1<<endl;
    }
    if(nProcs > 2*myRank+2)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" waiting from "<<2*myRank+2<<endl;
        MPI_Recv((void *)rightChild, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+2, 2*myRank+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status);
        cout<<myRank<<" got from "<<2*myRank+1<<endl;
    }
    //sum it up
    cout<<myRank<<" finding the min"<<endl;
    double myMin = min(min(leftChild[0], rightChild[0]), partialMin);
    //MPI_Send to (i+1)/2-1
    if(myRank!=0)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" sending "<<myMin<<" to "<<(myRank+1)/2 -1 <<endl;
        MPI_Send((void *)&myMin, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, (myRank+1)/2 - 1, myRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    double min;
    //MPI_Recv from (i+1)/2-1
    if(myRank!=0)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" waiting from "<<(myRank+1)/2-1<<endl;
        MPI_Recv((void *)&min, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, (myRank+1)/2 - 1, (myRank+1)/2 - 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status);
        cout<<myRank<<" got from "<<(myRank+1)/2-1<<endl;
    }
    totalMin = min;
    //MPI_send to 2*i+1 and 2*i+2
    if(nProcs > 2*myRank+1)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" sending to "<<2*myRank+1<<endl;
        MPI_Send((void *)&min, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+1, myRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if(nProcs > 2*myRank+2)
    {
        cout<<myRank<<" sending to "<<2*myRank+1<<endl;
        MPI_Send((void *)&min, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+2, myRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

PS: I know I can use

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce((void *)&partialMin, (void *)&totalMin, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast((void *)&totalMin, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But I want to write my own code for fun.

Comment: Actually all you need is a single `MPI_Allreduce` line. I'm not sure exactly how the scoping rules of C++ work, but it could be that `&min` returns the address of the `min` function instead of the address of the local variable with the same name.

Comment: If you're set on writing your own function instead of using the built-in stuff as @HristoIliev mentioned, you'll probably need to provide more debugging information. Did you try using gdb/ddd/TotalView to get a better idea of why exactly it's segfaulting?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did use gdb, and I know that it seg. faulted in the MPI Recv statement. I did not dig deeper. Since I was late in a project, I did to use MPI_Allreduce(). I will resume working my own implementation in some time.

Comment: I'm sooo blind that I didn't actually see that the error is in the first call to `MPI_Recv`... Now I see it: the reason for the error is simply the way you've declared `status`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the way you use the status argument in the receive calls. Instead of passing the address of an `MPI_Status` instance, you simply pass an uninitialised pointer and that leads to the crash:

```c
MPI_Status *status; // status declared as a pointer and never initialised
...
MPI_Recv((void *)&leftChild[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+1, 2*myRank+1,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, status); // status is an invalid pointer here
```

You should change your code to:

```c
MPI_Status status;
...
MPI_Recv((void *)&leftChild[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+1, 2*myRank+1,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Since you do not examine at all the status in your code, you can simply pass `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` in all calls:

```c
MPI_Recv((void *)&leftChild[0], 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 2*myRank+1, 2*myRank+1,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```